# core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket - why am I seeing this in Apache error log?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, virtualhost, ubuntu-14.04, php5

Does anyone know why do I keep seeing `core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket` in my Apache 2.4.7 (Ubuntu) error log and what does it mean?

I haven't noticed any problems so far, but it really hardens my reading of `error.log`. The log looks like this all the time:

```
    [Mon Apr 23 09:22:34.927673 2018] [core:trace6] [pid 6096] core_filters.c(527): [client 127.0.0.1:40876] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
    [Mon Apr 23 09:22:34.927793 2018] [core:trace6] [pid 6159] core_filters.c(527): [client 127.0.0.1:40868] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
    [Mon Apr 23 09:22:34.927892 2018] [core:trace6] [pid 6160] core_filters.c(527): [client 127.0.0.1:40870] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
    [Mon Apr 23 09:22:35.160482 2018] [core:trace6] [pid 6092] core_filters.c(527): [client 127.0.0.1:40866] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
    [Mon Apr 23 09:24:07.472559 2018] [core:trace5] [pid 6161] protocol.c(655): [client 127.0.0.1:40888] Request received from client: POST /index.php?module=000100 HTTP/1.1
    [Mon Apr 23 09:24:07.721570 2018] [core:trace6] [pid 6161] core_filters.c(527): [client 127.0.0.1:40888] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
    [Mon Apr 23 09:24:12.725587 2018] [core:trace6] [pid 6161] core_filters.c(527): [client 127.0.0.1:40888] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
    [Mon Apr 23 09:29:07.829907 2018] [core:trace5] [pid 6093] protocol.c(655): [client 127.0.0.1:41056] Request received from client: POST /index.php?module=000100 HTTP/1.1
    [Mon Apr 23 09:29:07.986466 2018] [core:trace6] [pid 6093] core_filters.c(527): [client 127.0.0.1:41056] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
    [Mon Apr 23 09:29:12.990794 2018] [core:trace6] [pid 6093] core_filters.c(527): [client 127.0.0.1:41056] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm replying to my own question, as I've found out what was the issue :)

The Apache virtual host config `LogLevel` directive was set to `trace6` (which can actually be seen in every line of the log: `[core:trace6]`), which makes the log quite detailed about what the server is doing.

Lowering down the level has lightened the error log output to more readable.

Details about Apache `LogLevel` directive: [Apache 2.4 LogLevel Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel)